# "Someone of the opposite gender" vs "Someone from the opposite gender"

Tags: word-choice, prepositions, phrase-choice, prepositional-verbs

Which one of these two structures is correct? Or can they be used interchangeably?

> "Someone of the opposite gender"

> "Someone from the opposite gender"

What I try to mean by these phrases is, "Someone who is a member of the opposite sex".

Let me make up some example sentences to provide a better picture in your mind:

- "He is always nervous when he is around someone of/from the opposite gender."
- "He thinks he can't be friends with someone of/from the opposite gender."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've only ever encountered "Someone of the opposite gender" so that's what I would use.  I think "Someone from the opposite gender" is perfectly understandable and seems like the same meaning, but I have never heard a native speaker say it exactly that way.

Comment: Thank you. I just noticed that in dictionaries, there are definitions for "the opposite sex", but not for "the opposite gender". I wonder if I made a mistake by saying "gender" instead of "sex" in the OP.